# App crashes when multiple files "write to file" simultaneously

Tags: iphone

Here is my code.

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *) connection

{
    //Each connection has its own "downloadedData".
    BOOL writeFlag = [downloadedData writeToFile: filePath atomically: YES];
}
```

I have multiple NSURLConnections at the same time.Each connection corresponds to one download item.App crashes when multiple downloads finish at the same time.Is this method thread-safe?

It says:

```
_serverConnectionDiedNotification. Info -- notification=NSConcreteNotification 0x11d90470{name = AVController_ServerConnectionDiedNotification; object = <AVController: 0x11d855a0>},
 AVController = <AVController: 0x11d855a0>,currentTime = 0.00

Program received signal:  “0”.
warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,I figure out myself.Besides downloadedData, I have a few arrays and dictionarys pair with each unique connection. Seems like I didn't take care of those collections carefully enough.
When I clear this mess up,phew,problems are gone!

Answer (score 1):

I assume downloadedData is not shared between the different requests? Because that would probably not be a good idea.

I use the [ASI-HTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library for my http request needs. It's easy to do things like asynchronous requests right. You might find it useful.

Comment: No,each connection has its own "downloadedData".Thanks for the tip for ASI-HTTPRequest library,though.